# Restrict Camel route to HTTP method

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel route definition like this one:

```
@Component
public class AggregateRouter extends AbstractRouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    super.configure();

    from("{{endpoint.users}}/{id}?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
      .to("bean:routeUtils?method=validateQueryParams"))
      .to("bean:routeUtils?method=loadRouteProperties"))
      .to("{{uri.api.users}}")
      .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Map.class)
      .to("bean:routeUtils?method=extractAndAddToProperty"))
      .to("bean:routeUtils?method=prepareAggregateRestCalls"))
      .multicast()
        .stopOnException()
        .to("seda:operation1")
        .to("seda:operation2")
      .end()
      .setBody(simple("${property.result}"))
      .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
      .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
      .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"));

    from("seda:operation2")
      .toD("{{uri.api.users.operation2}}")
      .unmarshal()
      .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, List.class)
      .to("bean:userService?method=addOp2"));

    from("seda:operation1")
      .toD("{{uri.api.users.operation1}}")
      .choice()
        .when(AbstractHelper::isOk)
          .unmarshal()
          .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, List.class)
          .to("bean:userService?method=addOp1"))
        .otherwise()
          .unmarshal()
          .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Map.class)
          .to("bean:userService?method=handleRouteSubscriptionException"))
      .end();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use this definition only when the HTTP request comes into the integration layer as a `GET` request. The issue now is: I have two more *operations* (`PUT` and `DELETE`), but I don't want a "special" processing for those two (at least for now)...and they are behaving as `GET` since this route definition is "intercepting" and handling the request(s).

I can't use a **Rest DSL** (the project is currently like). I also tried using the `&httpMethodRestrict` like `{{endpoint.users}}/{id}?matchOnUriPrefix=true&httpMethodRestrict=PUT` but it's not working also.

Any clues?

Comment: Is it possible to filter all non-GET requests?

Comment: I can do that also...and me a forward with them, but any `GET` requests that matches that URI must be processed by that route definition? Why? What do you have in mind?

Comment: After re-reading your question, i am not sure what you want achieve.. As far as I understand: {{endpoint.users}} is an http-endpoint. A request may be issued via GET, PUT or DELETE. You do not want them to be processed if the request is not a GET request. Is this correct?

Comment: It's an HTTP endpoint and I just want that route to be executed when a `GET` request comes (see the `from` definition). If something else comes in (`PUT`, `DELETE`, etc) on the same URL I don't want it to be processed by that route definition. Think about it like restricting that route definition to `GET` request(s) only.

Comment: i also think that httpMethodRestrict is the way to go. The docs are quite vague about the parameter... Try to use it like httpMethodRestrict=GET (read: restrict the requests to GET). Does this help?

Comment: Actually that's what I ended up using, although I thought there were another way of doing this; it can be messy if I want to do similar things within the same route definition. You can add it as an answer for future reference(s); I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also think that httpMethodRestrict is the way to go. The docs are quite vague about the parameter... Try to use it like httpMethodRestrict=GET (read: restrict the requests to GET)

Another possible solution might be using the header information **Exchange.HTTP_METHOD** like **.filter(header("Exchange.HTTP_METHOD").isEqualTo("GET"))** - just to get the idea (i didn't try it out)